# OnScoll called multiple times in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

While using this, if i scroll a small amount, why is onScroll() called for 20 or so times i.e 5-6 times for each `firstVisibleItem`. Why not its called once for each scroll action?

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                Log.d("hey","called"+firstVisibleItem);
            }

            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It is listening for any scroll, not just a start of a scroll.

Comment: as @zgc7009 said - scrolling is not a single action for which there is a single resulting method call. Scrolling is a continuous event, and the method is called continuously.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at implentation of `ListView`, you can see that `mOnScrollListener.onScroll` is called only once in ListView, actually in `invokeOnItemScrollListener()` method.

```
void invokeOnItemScrollListener() {
    if (mFastScroll != null) {
        mFastScroll.onScroll(mFirstPosition, getChildCount(), mItemCount);
    }
    if (mOnScrollListener != null) {
        mOnScrollListener.onScroll(this, mFirstPosition, getChildCount(), mItemCount);
    }
    onScrollChanged(0, 0, 0, 0); // dummy values, View's implementation does not use these.
}
```

So let's try find some usages of `invokeOnItemScrollListener()`. We got a lot, including usages in `AbsListView`. In `AbsListView`, `invokeOnItemScrollListener()` is called indirectly every time in `onTouchMove` method. So now, it should be clear why you receive `onScroll` callback so many times.